# SQL Server pivot query returns only one row

Tags: sql-server, pivot

**My data is like this:**

```
ID  ColumnName  columnnvalue
----------------------------- 
13  seraialnew   tester name
13  serial        123123
13  seraialnew    am444
13  serial        33333


SELECT  id,seraialnew,serial
  FROM (
   SELECT id,columnnvalue, ColumnName  FROM dbo.formValues
  ) cols
PIVOT(
    MAX(id)
    FOR ColumnName IN(seraialnew,serial)
)p
```

and get single row result instead multiple

Comment: ID's are all the same - `13`. That's why you get 1 row.

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Comment: i want to create dynamic result add column to  a table and add value in neasted child table and get result with this combination. when id add column to table this result add new column with record at below table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got same `id` there will be only one string, so I changed the id's for 2 of your rows:

```
;WITH formValues AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(13,'seraialnew','tester name'),
(13,'serial','123123'),
(14,'seraialnew','am444'),
(14,'serial','33333')
) as t(ID, ColumnName, columnnvalue)
)

SELECT  id,seraialnew,serial
  FROM (
   SELECT id,columnnvalue, ColumnName
   FROM formValues
  ) cols
PIVOT(
    MAX(columnnvalue)
    FOR ColumnName IN(seraialnew,serial)
)p
```

Will give you:

```
id  seraialnew  serial
13  tester name 123123
14  am444       33333
```

Another way:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  id,
            columnnvalue,
            ColumnName+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnName ORDER BY ColumnName) as nvarchar(1)) as ColumnName
    FROM formValues
) cols
PIVOT(
    MAX(columnnvalue)
    FOR ColumnName IN(seraialnew1,serial1,seraialnew2,serial2)
)p
```

With same `id = 13` will give you this:

```
id  seraialnew1 serial1 seraialnew2 serial2
13  am444       33333   tester name 123123
```